# Error while running Quantum Teleportation Algorithm on real device using qiskit on IBM-Q

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

I am trying to implement Quantum Teleportation Algorithm on an actual device, I am using IBM-Q Jupyter notebook for the same purpose.

The code is as follows:

```
import qiskit as qk
from qiskit import ClassicalRegister, QuantumRegister, QuantumCircuit
from qiskit import execute, Aer
from qiskit import IBMQ
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg'

def apply_secret_unitary(secret_unitary, qubit, quantum_circuit, dagger):
  functionmap = {
    'x': quantum_circuit.x,
    'y': quantum_circuit.y,
    'z': quantum_circuit.z,
    'h': quantum_circuit.h,
    't': quantum_circuit.t
  }
  if dagger == 1:
    functionmap['t'] = quantum_circuit.tdg

  if dagger:
    [functionmap[unitary](qubit) for unitary in secret_unitary]
  else:
    [functionmap[unitary](qubit) for unitary in secret_unitary[::-1]]

secret_unitary = 'hzxhzhx'

qc = QuantumCircuit(3, 1)
'''
qc[0] -> The qubit to be teleported
qc[1] -> entangled state, possessed by alice
qc[2] -> entangled state, possessed by bob
'''

apply_secret_unitary(secret_unitary, qc.qubits[0], qc, dagger = 0) 
qc.barrier()
qc.h(1)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.barrier()
qc.cx(0, 1)
qc.h(0)
qc.cx(1, 2)
qc.cz(0, 2)
apply_secret_unitary(secret_unitary, qc.qubits[0], qc, dagger = 1)
qc.barrier()
qc.measure(2, 0);
qc.draw(output= 'mpl')

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q')
provider.backends()

from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
backend = least_busy(provider.backends(filters = lambda b: b.configuration().n_qubits >= 3 and 
                                       not b.configuration().simulator and 
                                       b.status().operational == True))
job_exp = execute(qc, backend = backend, shots = 8192)
exp_result = job_exp.result()

exp_measurement_result = exp_result.get_counts()
print(exp_measurement_result)
plot_histogram(exp_measurement_result)
```

The error which the following code gives is:

```
IBMQJobApiError: "'400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://api.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs/5e73033786653e0018a2364e/resultDownloadUrl. Cannot get presigned download url., Error code: 3202.'"
```

I've tried deleting my account and load a new account using a newly generated token but that doesn't seem to work either.

Clicking the link in the error gives the following error:

```
OPERATION_NOT_AVAILABLE
404 Shared class "Hub" has no method handling GET /ibm-q/Groups/open/Projects/main/Jobs/5e72ff01121d5e0018bfe775/resultDownloadUrl.
code: 2411
```

perhaps, I am using a method which is now deprecated. How can I tackle this situation?

Comment: Can you try removing the barriers?

Comment: It remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I believe this is solved in @IEIrodov's answer below.

I'm not sure what's causing the issue, but based on similar issues on the qiskit slack channel, I don't think it's something you're doing.

As a workaround, try running:

```
exp_result = job_exp.result()
exp_measurement_result = exp_result.get_counts()
print(exp_measurement_result)
plot_histogram(exp_measurement_result)
```

Separately in a new cell.

(also, if you're trying to verify teleportation, you need to `apply_secret_unitary` on line 42 to `qc.qubits[2]` instead of `qc.qubits[0]`).

Comment: That's what I think as well, it doesn't seem to work that way either. Also, you're right about using qubit_2, that's a silly mistake on my side. thanks!

Comment: Okay, sorry I wasn't able to help more. Hopefully the issue will be fixed soon.

Comment: I've added a solution that worked for me, check it out!

Comment: @IEIrodov, I can't comment on your answer, but I'm glad you've solved it! Maybe I had just been waiting long enough between running the cells that the job could complete.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what had caused the problem but I was able to solve it and most likely know what the problem was.

Consider these two lines from my code above:

```
job_exp = execute(qc, backend = backend, shots = 8192)
exp_result = job_exp.result()
```

Problem with the above lines is that we are not waiting for the actual quantum device to compute and send over the data. To avoid this, we can use a method called `job_monitor` from `qiskit.tools.monitor` which when called, let us know whether the job is complete or not.

After it displays that the job has successfully run we should expect value from `result`

Following is the code for the same purpose:

```
IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub = 'ibm-q')
backend = least_busy(provider.backends(filters = lambda x: x.configuration().n_qubits >= 3
                                      and not x.configuration().simulator
                                      and x.status().operational == True))
print('least busy backend: ', backend)
```

```
from qiskit.tools.monitor import job_monitor
job = execute(qc, backend = backend, shots = 8192)
job_monitor(job)
```

Proceed further only after the output to the above cell becomes '*Job Status: job has successfully run*' which may take some time depending upon the value of shots.

After that, you can call result() and get_counts() to get the values:

```
result = job.result()
counts = result.get_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 3202 is a networking error when trying to get the requested page. In this case the results for your job.